# No F# Interactive: "Failed to spawn FSI, please ensure it's in PATH"

Tags: f#-interactive

Trying to get F# working in Visual Studio Code (it's working fine on my laptop).

Ionide-fsharp, Ionide-FAKE and Ionide-Paket extensions installed. 
[image]

When attempting to run a script in FSI (script selected, Alt-Enter), I get two messages (see images):
1) "Failed to send text to FSI.
2) "Failed to spawn FSI, please ensure it's in PATH.

- Notice that only Powershell is available in the dropdown, whereas on my laptop it shows "F# Interactive" too.
  [image]

I thought everything was included in the Ionide extensions and I have it working on my laptop.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I have the same issue, and if i run the command ``fsi`` in powershell, F# Interactive runs just fine, so it's obviously on my PATH